# Generate email on meta value update

Tags: login, user-roles, user-meta, email, account

I've implemented some meta fields for users like mobile number, address. It can be updated by user as well as admin, I wan't to trigger an email to user and admin stating about the updated field value if any value is updated, irrespective of who updates it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [profile_update hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/profile_update/) to perform actions on post save

```
function wpse_264096_send_email( $user_id, $old_user_data ) {

    // Get the user object for $user_id
    $user = get_user_by( 'ID', $user_id );
    $user_email = $user->data->email;

    /** You can get any meta fields by this, just change 'meta_key' to the key desired
      * True means its a single value, it will output as a string.
      * If you set to false you get an array with the meta_value, handy if there are multiple values.
      */
    $user_meta = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'meta_key', true );

    // Send e-mail to the user
    $message = "Your information has changed. Your new <META KEY> is now <$user_meta>";
    wp_mail( $user_email, 'Your information has been updated', $message );

    // Send e-mail to the site admin
    $message = "A users information has changed. The new <META KEY> is now <$user_meta>";
    wp_mail( get_option( 'admin_email' ), 'Your information has been updated', $message );

}
add_action( 'profile_update', 'wpse_264096_send_email', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: It's not related to a post, its related with user's meta value, I need to trigger email on "update_user_meta".

Comment: What, if I need to include the changed field details, for example if admin has changed mobile number for any user, so how can I generate an email with the new value to the user?

Comment: The second paramter is the old user data, meaning this hook is fired after the update process. Meaning you can get the user object and any meta value like you would normally do. I've updated my answer again to help you out with two emails, one to the user and one to the site admin. You can literally just do whatever in this function really.

Comment: How can I compare between old and new user data, and find which field's value is changed? Currently email generates even if no value is changed.

Comment: The old data is right there and how to get the new data is already in my code as an example. Comparing two pieces of data is really PHP 101

Comment: for example, if I need to compare change in meta_key (name of my meta_key if phone), 
get_user_meta( $user_id, 'phone', true );
fetches the updated value of phone, and how can I get the old value of phone?

Comment: Maybe you should actually read my answer, it's been answered there in the first 2 lines.

Comment: I'm unable to sort this out, adding this generates an email even if there's no change and update profile is clicked, although I can pass the value of meta key in the email but I want ti trigger email only when a particular meta key is updated.

Comment: I'm gonna stop replying. Your question is answered and you refuse to read the slightest bit of documentation. If you can't figure out how to compare two variables that are already available I suggest you ask a new question at stackoverflow.com

Comment: I was asking repeatedly because `$old_user_data ->phone;` is also returning the current value which is the updated one. 
both `$user_meta = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'phone', true );` and `$old_user_data ->phone;` are returning same values.
I'm still unable to figure out.

Comment: Can you help me with this? I've tried to figure out but I'm getting same values, because of this email is being generated every time when update button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress triggers a custom hook when certain meta is updated, user meta counts. See [`updated_{$meta_type}_meta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/updated_(meta_type)_meta). Here's an example use case:

```
add_action('updated_user_meta', function( $meta_id, $user_id, $meta_key, $_meta_value ) {
    switch ( $meta_key ) {
        case 'mobile_number':
        case 'address':

            $user = new \WP_User($user_id);

            // user
            wp_mail($user->user_email, 'Profile updated', 'Profile updated.');

            // admin
            wp_mail(get_bloginfo('admin_email'), 'Profile updated', "Profile updated for user {$user->display_name}.");
            break;
    } 
}, 0, 4);
```

Comment: email is not generating.

Comment: make sure you have the right `$meta_key`. Read the code and adjust it before posting comments or at least provide what you did.

Comment: The meta_key for my mobile number field is phone. I've added this snippet in functions.php

`add_action('updated_user_meta', function( $meta_id, $user_id, $meta_key, $_meta_value ) {
    switch ( $meta_key ) {
        case 'phone':
        

            $user = new WP_User($user_id);

            // user
            wp_mail($user->user_email, 'Profile updated', 'Profile updated.');

            // admin
            wp_mail(get_bloginfo('admin_email'), 'Profile updated', "Profile updated for user {$user->display_name}.");
            break;
    } 
}, 0, 4);`